# Spring boot CORS error only for deployed service

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, cors

I have the below method to configure CORS:

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200", "http://localhost:4201", "http://<ip_address>");
            }
        };
    }
```

*I put <ip_address> intentionally here. It has the actual and working ip of the deployed angular app.*

I have two spring-boot services and current scenarios are:

**Scenarios:-**

Service-1 (uses spring-security) :- Above method works fine for both local and deployed service.

Service-2 (does not use spring-security) :- Above method works fine for local but getting CORS error for deployed service.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the CORS configuration is correctly set up for Service-1, which uses Spring Security, both locally and when deployed. However, Service-2, which does not use Spring Security, is experiencing CORS errors when deployed. For **Service-2**, which does not use Spring Security, additional configurations might be **necessary to handle CORS properly**.

You can create a `CorsFilter` and enable `CorsFilter` to handle CORS for **Service-2**.